# Number of tangents from a point to a curve

Tags: calculus

> what are the number of tangents that  can be  drawn from the point $(\frac{-1}{2},0)$ to the curve $y=e^{\{x\}}$.Here { } denotes the fractional part function

what I have done:Since we cannot differentiate the fractional part function I removed the fractional part function as follows

y=$e^x$, $ x\in [0,1)$

y=$e^{x-1}$, $ x\in [1,2)$

y=$e^{x+1}$, $ x\in [-1,0)$

y=$e^{x+2}$, $ x\in [-2,-1)$

Now,just for a try I found out the tangent from the given point to curve y=$e^x$, $ x\in [0,1)$ and the equation of tangent comes out to be $y-\sqrt{e}=\sqrt{e}(x-\frac{1}{2})$.I have checked that x coordinate of point of contact of tangent on curve belongs in the interval [0,1).So,this process gives one tangent by hit and trial method but I wanted to know some general method to find the number of tangents.Please help

Comment: Hint: try plotting the function, (also no need to find the equation of the tangents, you are only asked the number)

Comment: Hint for plotting, no need to break {x} into it's definition every time, just use that it will always lie between [0,1) for all x and hence your function lies between [1,e) for all x

Comment: I have rough plotted the function also but it doesn't help

Comment: That's not possible, anyway do you have the answer to this problem?

Comment: yes it is 1 only

Comment: As implicitly said by my colleagues: if there is a "neater" way to tackle the question, it is by first remarking that your function is _1-periodical_.

Comment: Ya but what to do after that @JeanMarie

Comment: Who said that you cannot differentiate ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust what i meant to say was we can't differentiate fractional part function directly,first we will have to break the function into intervals so that there is no fractional part function in it.

Comment: @KartikWatwani: actually, you can, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_{0}\in [n,n+1)$ and $y_{0}=e^{x_{0}-n}$, then

$y'(x_{0})=e^{x_{0}-n}$,

now the equation of tangent is

$y-e^{x_{0}-n}=e^{x_{0}-n}(x-x_{0}) \quad \cdots \cdots (*)$,

put $(-\frac{1}{2},0)$ into $(*)$,

$-e^{x_{0}-n}=e^{x_{0}-n}(-\frac{1}{2}-x_{0})$

$x_{0}=\frac{1}{2}$,

$n=0$

[image]

**Edit: Had misread the question initially, many thanks to Tony K's comment**

Comment: I'm being totally intuitive here, but I think the "arcs" which are really far from the point won't have any tanget going through that point.

Comment: This is simply wrong.

Comment: @TonyK, wait for your correct answer

Comment: "Therefore there's one tangent...": surely you can see that this is wrong? Whether or not I post an answer.

Comment: @TonyK, I've rearranged the sentence structure, is that OK?

Comment: No. The tangent has to go through $(-\frac12,0)$, and nearly all of them don't.

Comment: @TonyK, Thanks you a lot, I've misread most important thing.  Let me corrected then.

Answer (score 0):

The function is continuous and differentiable, except at integer values, where it is continuous and differentiable on the right only. At any point $x=x_0$, the (right-hand) derivative is $e^{\{x_0\}}$, and this can be taken for the slope of the tangent.

We have the tangent equation

$$y=e^{\{x_0\}}(x-x_0)+e^{\{x_0\}}=e^{\{x_0\}}(x-x_0+1).$$

It goes through the given point when

$$0=e^{x_0}(-\frac12-x_0+1)$$
or
$$x_0=\frac12,\\
y=e^{1/2}(x+\frac12).$$
This is the only solution.